# ContentFilters of RadEditor seems only to be applied when toggling html view

Tags: telerik, radeditor

I am using a RadEditor with the ContentFilters `MakeUrlsAbsolute` and `DefaultFilters` like

```
<telerik:RadEditor ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" EnableResize="True"
  EditModes="Design, HTML, Preview" 
  ContentFilters="MakeUrlsAbsolute,DefaultFilters"
  ToolbarMode="Default" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="True"
  ContentAreaMode="Div"/>
```

(the tag contains a lot more that is ommitted for brevity)

In my code behind, I am using code to setup the ImageManager like

```
var viewImages = new [] { "/MyImages" };
RadEditor1.ImageManager.UploadPaths = viewImages;
RadEditor1.ImageManager.ViewPaths = viewImages;
RadEditor1.ImageManager.DeletePaths = viewImages;
```

and then I create a virtual directory in IIS, named MyImages in which I place some image files.

The images are found by the rad editor when I click the image icon and when I save the contents of the radeditor, I am saving RadEditor1.Content in the database.

However, image urls will not become absolute by doing this, which I expected the content filter `MakeUrlsAbsolute` to accomplish.

To be able to have those urls absolute, it seems like I have to toggle between design view and html view at least once, and then I can retrieve the content.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The content filters are executed when submitting the page/form and when switching to HTML mode.

Can you set the ContentAreaMode to "iframe" and the ContentFilters property to "MakeUrlsAbsolute,ConvertToXhtml" and test again?